# 質問一覧ページのタイトルが英語になっている

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

未回答の質問ページ ([/unanswered](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)) を見ていたら、ページタイトル (タブ名) が以下の画像のように"**Highly scored unanswered question**"と英語になっていることに気づきました。

本来ならタブ名が他の「新着の質問」や「アクティブな質問」などと同様に「未回答の質問」というふうに日本語でタブ名が構成されると思うのですが、この状態では英語版と見分けがつかない状態です。

自分で翻訳リクエストを送ってもどうにもならないと思ったので、ここで質問をさせていただきました。

**画像：**[image: 未翻訳]

Comment: 「自分で翻訳リクを送ってもどうにもならない」ことは無いと思いますよ。
対象の翻訳文字列は https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15866 かなと思います。
（ただ、私のブラウザでは、その「タブ」というのは表示されていません）

Comment: 恐らくブラウザの「ページタイトル」を指していると思われるので、そのように編集しました。単に「タブ」だとページ内でのコンポーネントとしてのタブとで分かりづらいかなと。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

コメントで言及されている通り、該当の文字列は https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15866 かと思われるので、「高スコアで未回答な質問」と訳してみました。
(サイトに反映されるまで数日程度待ってみてください)

**追記:**
何度か更新はかかっているはずなのに反映される気配がないため、MSE にも投稿しました。

[Title of unanswered page cannot be translated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380830)