# 最後に翻訳の反映が行なわれたのはいつですか？

Tags: サポート, 調査中, 翻訳

[一部のページのタイトルが英語になっている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3752/3054)問題ですが、未だに翻訳は反映されていません。この奇妙な現象に関し、私は全ての翻訳が新たには反映されなくなっているのではないか、と疑っています。

これを確認するために、最後に翻訳の反映が行なわれた（はずの）日時を教えて下さい。現在ですと、`rev 2022.8.30.42944` という文字がサイトの末尾にありますが、この日付け（8月30日）ということになりますでしょうか。

---

9月1日追記: 翻訳が反映されたのを確認しました。サイト末尾の文字列も `rev 2022.9.1.42954` に変わっています。これが関係あるのでしょうか。いずれにせよ、翻訳の反映のタイミングがどうなっているのか、教えていただければと思います。

Comment: do you happen to have an example? I'm after: a URL where I can see the string in English and a translation on Traducir that was approved for that text. I can follow it up with the appropriate people

Comment: @g3rv4 From around the end of July, for about a month, all the new translation strings that I know were not reflected on the site.
However, it seems that everything was reflected around September 1st.
Currently, translations are reflected promptly.
If I find the issue again, I will share the URL.

Answer (score 3):

2018年に [ja.traducir](https://ja.traducir.win/)が導入された際、開発者からの情報によれば、翻訳はビルド時に即座に反映される仕組みとなっていました。当時の手順メモは以下の通りです。

1. ユーザーが Traducir で新しい翻訳を提案
2. レビュー担当者が承認
3. Traducir が新しい翻訳を Transifex にプッシュ
4. 開発者が SO のビルドを行うとき、Transifex からすべての翻訳をプル
5. ビルドが完了すると、新しい文字列がサイトに反映

しかし近年、ビルドが完了しても反映されないことが繰り返し起こっています。現在、CMの方からエンジニアリングチームに反映できない理由の確認を依頼しておりますが、返答に時間を要しているようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。今後、ビルドが更新されても翻訳が反映されていない際には報告をした方が良いですか？ それとも、既知の問題であるため不要でしょうか。

Comment: はい、ビルドが更新されても翻訳が反映されていない Traducir のstrings を（わかる範囲で）リストアップする必要があるのではないか、と考えていたところでした‍♀️

Comment: リストアップ大変すぎますし、必要無いと思います。
単に、古い翻訳ファイルのままなだけだと思いますので。
もし、デプロイ担当者などがログを確認の上で、最新の翻訳ファイルが反映されているはずだ、と回答した場合は反証として、未翻訳箇所を示す必要が有りますが、その際も数カ所で十分だと思います。

Comment: 私のコメントの「翻訳が反映されていない際」の報告というのは、ビルドされたはずなのに翻訳ファイルが反映されなかった、時点という意味です。例えばチャットで報告した後も、私が確認しただけで rev 2023.11.30.1774、rev 2023.11.30.1797、rev 2023.11.30.1842 とビルトが上がっていますが、翻訳は更新されていません。
こういった際に、確認した rev 番号などを報告し続けた方が良いのかな、という疑問です。

Comment: 承知いたしました、それではリストアップ化せずに ！最近ですと、mjyさんとsupaさんが Traducir にて翻訳くださったものが、実際にサイトに反映されているのかどうか私の目で確認することができませんでした。ですので (もちろん可能な範囲で) rev 番号を報告いただけると大変ありがたいです。